# How to use the countGreaterThan method from Oracle tutorial?

Tags: java, arrays, generics, methods

I'm currently learning java on the official Oracle website and I have copy pasted the code below. There is nothing wrong with the code, but the thing is I don't know how to use it. It is suppose to be a method that counts the number of elements in an array `T[]` that are greater than a specified element elem. Can someone please show me an example of how to use this method?

```
public static <T extends Comparable<T>> int countGreaterThan(T[] anArray, T elem) {
    int count = 0;
    for (T e : anArray) {
        if (e.compareTo(elem) > 0) {
            ++count;
        }
    }
    return count;
}

public interface Comparable<T> {

    public int compareTo(T o);
}
```

Comment: add a link to the guide with the code

Comment: You should check out additional tutorials on how to call methods such as this one: http://www.homeandlearn.co.uk/java/java_method_calling.html or the oracle tutorial on calling methods. How have you tried to call it? What errors have you gotten?

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/boundedTypeParams.html

Comment: first learn the java fundamentals from basic tutorials, dont get involve in such kind of stuff. below link would help you. LINK: http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/

Comment: Please don't link anything unless you're going to summarize it here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1- You should use a Generic class that implements `interface Comparable<T>` for example `public class ArrayCode<T> implements Comparable<T>`

2-To use `countGreaterThan(T[] anArray, T elem)` method you should override `compareTo(T o)` method for example

```
@Override
public int compareTo(T o) {

    if(this.equals(o)){
        return 1;
    }else{
        return 0;
    }
}
```

3- After that you can use any Class (Integer, String, Person ...) to replace the generic `T`, an example to test this method:

```
Integer[] marks = new Integer[] {12,0,15,18,4};
    int av = ArrayCode.countGreaterThan(marks, 10);
    System.out.println("the number of Marks that are greater than 10 is: "+av);
```

And the result is:

```
the number of Marks that are greater than 10 is: 3
```

NB: 
1- I use `ArrayCode.countGreaterThan(marks, 10);` because `countGreaterThan()` is `static` method.

2- You must also add `(Comparable<T>)` cast to `e` because The method `compareTo(T)` is undefined for the type `T` like that `if (((Comparable<T>) e).compareTo(elem) > 0)`

Answer (score 9):

This is using Java Generics, which means that this code can be used on different class types.  The 'T' is a place holder for the type of object it's operating on, and it will be determined based on an actual call.  This particular method can be used on an array of any class and an element of the same class, as long as the class implements the Comparable interface (so that it has a compareTo() method).

Some example uses:

```
Integer[] intList = new Integer[] {1,77,43,45,4};
int x = countGreaterThan(intList, 5);
```

Comment: Thanks @DBug, really appreciate your help!!